# Summing up value of same observations in SPSS

Tags: spss, cumulative-sum

My data set is a financial one. We have investors' buying-selling activities. During one year investors bought and sold stocks many times. I want to calculate total buyings of each investor. For example, collect each investors buyings and calculate the total buying.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We might be able to help with your problem, if you supply some more information (use the "Edit" link above) - describe the structure of your data, add a sample of your data, described what you tried to do so far, and what were the problems you ran into.

Comment: Thank you. I think I have found the answer. There is a "aggregate" function in SPSS and this function sums the values of same observation (case).